# I cant find hidden pictures and videos on my samsung note 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

O year ago I took a bunch of pictures and videos on my Samsung note 3 but I can't find them now but when I plug the phone into a laptop I can see all the pictures and videos how do I delete them. I need this done ASAP.

Comment: Does deleting them from the laptop not work?

Answer (score 1):

When you plug the phone into your laptop and see the pictures what folder are you looking at? You ought to be able to simply delete them via your PC. If you can see them you can trash them.

In order to view the files on your phone using your phone you will need to utilize a file browser / file manager application. There are many free ones in the app store of your choice.